# Declare a global variable with certain type

Tags: python, variables, types, global-variables

In python, is it possible to declare a global variable with a type?
I know this is fine to declare a local variable like this.

```
student: Student
```

Or

```
global student
```

But I'm looking for something like this

```
global student: Student
```

Comment: Python is a typeless language. More precisely ducktype one.

Comment: Python variables are not typed, and python doesn't have variable declarations, so the answer is "No".

Comment: I am guessing you referring mypy static code analysis typing. Try declaring student :Student = None in the module level. Than in the function which uses it declare it as global.

Comment: @LiorCohen It makes sense!

Comment: @LiorCohen, you should promote your comment to an Answer. Although SergeyA's answer is technically correct, your comment correctly handles code-analysis (in my case, telling PyCharm that the None variable really had certain properties, and to stop greying-out my code).

Answer (score 1):

I did it like this:

```
from typing import Union
from my_class import MyClass

foo_my_class: Union[MyClass, None] = None

def setup_function():
    """ test setup """
    global foo_my_class
    foo_my_class = MyClass()
...
```

I.e., this is a test module, and I want `foo_my_class` to be available at global scope for every test in the module. The `setup_function()` runs before every test, so I re-initialize `foo_my_class` each time (so that it is fresh and clean for each test).

`foo_my_class` still has to be declared at global scope, and it makes most sense to me to init to None, hence the Union typing. You don't *need* to do it like this, but if you don't initialize here, flake8 will complain. There are a few other ways to do this, but this one works and satisfies my linters (flake8, pylint, mypy).

Answer (score -1):

There are no set types for python variables, so you just need to declare global variable - which would automatically be any variable declared outside of a function scope.

Comment: Python now has dynamic typing: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html  https://realpython.com/lessons/dynamic-vs-static/